# Regular expression to match all characters between <h1> tag

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I'm using sublime text 2 editor. I would like to use regex to match all character between all `h1` tags.

As of now i'm using like this

```
<h1>.+</h1>
```

Its working fine if the h1 tag doesn't have breaks.

I mean for

```
<h1>Hello this is a hedaer</h1>
```

its working fine.

But its not working if the tag look like this

```
<h1>
   Hello this is a hedaer
</h1>
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

By default `.` matches every character except new line character.

In this case, you will need DOTALL option, which will make `.` matches any character, including new line character. DOTALL option can be specified inline as `(?s)`. For example:

```
(?s)<h1>.+</h1>
```

However, you will see that it will not work, since the default behavior of the quantifier is **greedy** (in this case its `+`), which means that it will try to consume as many characters as possible. You will need to make it **lazy** (consume as few characters as possible) by adding extra `?` after the quantifier `+?`:

```
(?s)<h1>.+?</h1>
```

---

Alternatively, the regex can be `<h1>[^<>]*</h1>`. In this case, you don't need to specify any option.

Comment: With OP's regex, specifying those options are not sufficient.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I have tried your code. But its still not matching when the tag contain break

Comment: Wouldn't that third regex break if you have any nested tags in h1? Like span or link or whatever... I just tried the "(?s)" and it works in sublime, that's cool.

Comment: I never knew you could specify flags in regex searches in sublime - thanks for the information @Some1.Kill.The.DJ

Comment: @enrey yes it would break..but even the 1st and 2nd regex can break if there is another h1 tag in h1 itself

Comment: Not sure how you guys figure this stuff out. Where is the documentation on regex search like this?

Comment: Works great, slight improvement to get all h tags:
/<h[1-6]>[^<>]*<\/h[1-6]>/g  (JS regex expression)
BTW you can use jQuery $(el).text() to get just the text content.

Answer (score 26):

Since this question is the top Google results search for a regex trying to find all the characters *between* an h1 tag I thought I would give that answer as well. Since that was what I was looking for.

```
(?s)(?<=<h1>)(.+?)(?=</h1>)
```

That regex, if used on a sample text like `<h1>A title</h1> <p>Some content</p> <h1>Another title</h1>` will only return `A title`.

Comment: This also works to clear chars between consecutive tags like (?s)(?<=</h1>)(.+?)(?=<h1>)