# cannot use some reg exp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all text between html tag after I searched the relevant topic I found [`(?s)<h1>.+?</h1>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525286/regular-expression-to-match-all-characters-between-h1-tag) can solve my problem but I can use this in JavaScript.Is there any Reg Exp similar this Reg Exp and can use in JavaScript.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `[\s\S]+`...............

Comment: @PranavCBalan It work great ! thank you.

Comment: @Tim007 you answer is wrong when there is newline or space characters between tags.

Comment: @JLRishe Thank you. I just want to delete specific some tags (include content between them) not all HTML tags.

Comment: @MonicSabaic Be that as it may, why don't you parse the HTML and then use the DOM to make the changes you want? There's rarely a reason to use string manipulation to modify HTML.

Comment: @JLRishe I forgot about it !, Thank you. Anyway I've just faced new problem and have to use reg exp again (remove tags but keep text between tags)

Comment: @Tim007 Good answer. I've just use to solve another problem.