# Check if custom field has h2 heading inside with regex

Tags: regex, wordpress

How can I check if a custom fiel called `description` has a heading inside the text?

**Take this as an example:**

```
<h2>whatever in the heading</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
```

Comment: `var_dump( preg_match( '<h2>', $description ) );`

Comment: here is an explanation of what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525286/regular-expression-to-match-all-characters-between-h1-tag

Answer (score 0):

If `description` is your field name then you can try with this code.

```
<?php
    $title = get_field( 'description' ); // <h2>whatever in the heading</h2>
    if ( strpos( $title, '<h2>' ) !== false) {
        echo 'H2 is exist.';
    } else {
        //Your Statement
    }
?>
```